# 3D graphics render as though no illumination

Tags: graphics, rendering, lighting

As you can see from the image below, when I plot 3D surfaces, regions, etc, they render as though there was no light source (left is Mathematica's help documentation, right is how it renders for me):

```
RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^3 - z^2 > 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image: comparison of documentation vs. evaluated]

This is just an example - but it happens every time.

Weirdly, when I rotate the image, the rendering temporarily renders normally - but only while I'm rotating; the moment I release the mouse, it goes back to being light-less.

Any idea what's wrong, and how to fix it?

I'm not aware of having made any preference changes - wouldn't know how to...

I use Mathematica 12.1.00 for MacOs X (64-bit). And I should add that the problem has been going on for months - restarts make no difference, global clearing makes no difference.

**UPDATE:**

In answer to @Edmund's question below, the `Lighting` setting makes no difference. Here is an example with `Lighting->"Standard"`:

[image]

And if I click to rotate the same graphic, it suddenly looks like this - but ***only*** while I am rotating it:

[image]

Comment: For reference, what version and OS are you using?

Comment: Does this persist if you quit Mathematica and restart?

Comment: I use Mathematica 12.1.0.0 for MacOs X (64-bit). And, yes, the problem persists - I'll add these two items to the question, thank you.

Comment: What does `Options[RegionPlot3D, Lighting]` return when evaluated?

Comment: Hi @Edmund. It returns `*{Lighting -> Automatic}*`. However, I have now tried adjusting the `Lighting` setting to `"Standard"` and `"Directional"` and the problem remains...

Comment: Mathematica uses a low quality render when rotating and the problem only appears when you stop and it switches to high quality. So you could try going to your Mathematica Preferences > Appearance and set anti-aliasing quality to zero. Though it's probably not anti-aliasing related - to me it looks more like what happens with Phong/Gouraud shading when vertex normals are reversed.

Comment: See the docs ref/VertexNormals https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexNormals.html: _Normals in opposite directions may cause unwanted banding effects in some 3D renderers..._ . They use `RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingEngine" -> "Metal"}`. Try changing `"Metal"` to `"OpenGL"`

Comment: Try this in a `Style` like so `Style[Graphics3D[Sphere[]], RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingEngine" -> #}]&/@{"Metal","OpenGL","Mesa"}`

Comment: Hi @flinty. Yes, that works - but it's incredibly cumbersome. Is there a way to set it as a default?

Comment: It also doesn't explain why the `RegionPlot3D` in the MMA documentation comes out properly rendered, but the exact same code (copied and pasted) doesn't come out that way in a notebook - see image in my OP...

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward fantastic. Also I found this https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1905659 - you can do `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingEngine" -> "OpenGL"}]` or you can also change your global options. As for the plots in the docs, does the problem go away if the plot in your notebook is scaled down? The plots in the docs are usually small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm turning my recommendations in the comments into an answer for anyone experiencing the same issue:

There is a bug in the Metal renderer on macOS. See here: 
 https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1905659

Execute the following to see which rendering engine works best.

```
Style[Graphics3D[Sphere[]], RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingEngine" -> #}]&/@{"Metal","OpenGL","Mesa"}
```

You can set the option once for all plots like this:

`SetOptions[$FrontEnd, RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingEngine" -> "OpenGL"}]`

... or you can add this to global options or init.m.