# Plot3D lighting issue

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, lighting

`Plot3D` is giving me very weird lighting. If I run the following line of code from the `Plot3D` documentation.

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

I get

[image]

This looks nothing like that shown in the documentation  (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html?q=Plot3D) and is clearly not what it is meant to be.

When I drag and rotate the image with the mouse it appears with "normal" lighting (as in the website), but when I finish dragging/rotating the image with the mouse the lighting goes back to that shown in the image.

I'm running: 12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020). Fresh install. As far as I am aware I have changed no default options at all.

Edit: simply reevaluating the code in the notebook for the help text results in the lighting changing.

Edit: I have uploaded a video of the problem https://youtu.be/dfDLeLiZlBQ

Comment: I am running V12.1.1 on MacOS and I can not reproduce your problem. I get the the normal default lighting.

Comment: I have tried a (another) complete reinstall of Mathematica (all preference files etc). Still the same issue. What version of macOS are you using? Are you using the same build of Mathematica?

Comment: Video of the problem here https://youtu.be/dfDLeLiZlBQ

Comment: See this answer here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/223714/72682 and try `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingEngine" -> "OpenGL"}]`

Comment: @flinty Thats it! Very bizarre bug. Switching to the OpenGL renderer fixes it. I can also confirm that it appears to be a multiple monitor issue. With the Metal renderer on the built in display alone it works fine. However, as soon as an external monitor is plugged in the lighting is broken as described. Unplug the monitor and it goes back to working as it should. For the OpenGL renderer it appears quite happy regardless as to whether an external monitor is plugged in or not. Do you want to post the comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @flyingmind It has already been answered so I voted to close as a duplicate. There's another answer on that question about the integrated gpu and multiple monitors.

Comment: It is a bug; from Wolfram: "It is the case that 3D graphics using the 'Metal' rendering engine are not displaying correctly. As an immediate workaround, you can evaluate

SetOptions[$FrontEnd, RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingEngine" -> "OpenGL"}]

Our developers are aware of the issue, and we hope to have it resolved in the next version of Mathematica"